# Copy a class into another

Tags: php, clone

I have

```
class A
{
    $a;
    $b;
    $c
}
```

And

```
class B
{
    $a;
    $b;
    $e;
    $f
}
```

How can i copy all common property from A to B? I already try the clone method but it only give me 2 objects A.

Is there any way to do it generically?

Comment: it's called inheritance :) `class B extends A`

Comment: ... or, if for some reasons you cannot make `B` class a child of `A` class, just use composition: add `$objectOfClassA` as a property of `B` class.

Comment: Are you sure about inheritance? $c is not present in B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for `class` "copying", then do it via overriding via `extends` keyword:

```
class A
{
   public $a, $b, $c;
}

class B extends A
{
   public $d, $e, $f;
}
```

-now your `B` will inherit all properties from `A` which are not private (so `$a`, `$b` and `$c` as well)

But if it's about objects (for example, your classes are not related anyhow) - then use [`get_object_vars()`](https://www.php.net/get_object_vars) to iterate:

```
class A
{
    public $a=1;
    public $b=2;
    public $c=3;
}

class B
{
    public $a=5;
    public $b=6;
    public $e=7;
    public $f=8;
}

$foo = new A;
$bar = new B;

foreach(get_object_vars($foo) as $name=>$value)
{
    if(property_exists($bar, $name))
    {
        $bar->$name = $value;
    }
}
```

-check the [fiddle](http://3v4l.org/UluQF). Note, that properties must be visible (public) to do this.

Comment: Oh thanks, this is mostly what I expected! Is it still possible if property are private but have public getter and setter with get_class_methods?

Comment: Normally, you should not do that with private/public properties. But - yes, if that will be needed for some reason, you'll have to use setters - and, perhaps, [Reflection API](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php)

Answer (score -1):

First way (inheritance) http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php

```
<?php

class A {
    public $_x = 'x';
    public $_y = 'y';
    public $_z = 'zz';
}

class B extends A {

    public function __construct() {
        echo $this->_x . "__" . $this->_y . "__" . $this->_z;
    }
}

$b = new B; // x__y__zz

?>
```

Second way - class instantiation - properties are public, so you can access their values from the object instance, and assign it to you inner properties

```
<?php

class AA {
    public $_x = 'x';
    public $_y = 'y';
    public $_z = 'zz';
}

class BB {
    public $_x, $_y, $_z;
    private $_AA;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->_AA = new AA();
        $this->_x = $this->_AA->_x;
        $this->_y = $this->_AA->_y;
        $this->_z = $this->_AA->_z;
        echo $this->_x . "__" . $this->_y . "__" . $this->_z;
    }
}

$bb = new BB; // x__y__zz

?>
```

Third way, if properties are private, and if you have direct access to the base class, you can make accessors to then, so even they cannot be overwritten from outside, their value can be accessed

```
<?php

class AAA {
    private $_x = 'x';
    private $_y = 'y';
    private $_z = 'zz';

    public function getX() {
        return $this->_x;
    }
    public function getY() {
        return $this->_y;
    }
    public function getZ() {
        return $this->_z;
    }
}

class BBB {
    public $_x, $_y, $_z;
    private $_AAA;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->_AAA = new AAA();
        $this->_x = $this->_AAA->getX();
        $this->_y = $this->_AAA->getY();
        $this->_z = $this->_AAA->getZ();
        echo $this->_x . "__" . $this->_y . "__" . $this->_z;
    }
}

$bbb = new BBB; // x__y__zz
```

---

Generic :)

```
<?php

class AAA {
    private $_x = 'x';
    private $_y = 'y';
    private $_z = 'zz';

    public function getX() {
        return $this->_x;
    }
    public function getY() {
        return $this->_y;
    }
    public function getZ() {
        return $this->_z;
    }
}

class BBB {
    public $_x, $_y, $_z;
}

$AAA = new AAA();
$BBB = new BBB();
$get = 'get';
$arr_AAA = (array)$AAA;
foreach($arr_AAA as $key => $value) {
    $property = explode('_', $key);
    $property = ucfirst($property[1]);
    $getter[] = $get.$property;
}
$i = 0;
foreach (get_object_vars($BBB) as $k=>$v) {
        $get = $getter[$i];
        $BBB->$k = $AAA->$get();
        $i++;
}

var_dump($BBB);
/**
object(BBB)[2]
  public '_x' => string 'x' (length=1)
  public '_y' => string 'y' (length=1)
  public '_z' => string 'zz' (length=2)
 * 
 */
```

This should work for i.e.

```
private $_qwe = 'qwe';
public getQwe() {
   return $this->_qwe;
}
```

It will uppercase the first letter as it should be the convention of the getters. Ofcourse you can build your own convention.

Comment: @Royal_BG Your code consider all my variables are some string

Comment: @goto it's not true. you can have `$_this->qwe = new SomeClass()`. Afterwards the copy of `qwe` will be `object(BBB)[3]
  public '_qwe' => 
    object(SomeClass)[2]
      public 'x' => null` just tested it. No matter what your properties contain they will be copied